# DexGuard java.io.IOException: The same input jar

Tags: android, dexguard

I'm facing this issue when using dexguard

```
> Task :app:dexguardStaging FAILED
```

The TaskInternal.execute() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. There are better ways to re-use task logic, see https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:reusing_task_logic.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexguardStaging'.

  > java.io.IOException: The same input jar [/Users/radityagumay/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar] is specified twice.

Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**
i've fix this issue by revert to distribution gradle 3.5 previously i using 4.3,

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
```

and downgrade all build from 3.0.0 to 2.3.3, remove maven google.com

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

This issue happened, when i using Android Studio 3 with build gradle 3.0.0 or 3.0.1, and dexguard (7.3.11) also use (8.0.18) enable.

this maybe mismatch version latest gradle with version of dexguard.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give me screenshot of logcat? so i identify what is exact problem.

Comment: just updated it, only that i got.

Comment: @ChetanPatel It is a build error, not runtime error, so no logcat.

Comment: Look like you're including the SDK library twice.

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, i had several module which using difference support-v4 version. but i've merge those with same version.

Comment: i know build error. but what is exact issue
may be multidex problem

Comment: @ChetanPatel Again: you're asking for logcat but if there's a build error there can be no logcat because there's no APK

Comment: No, it is including twice `android.jar`, not support library. It is specified on the error message you posted.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works

Comment: hi ChetanPatel and m0skit0 thanks for helping, i've fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code & let me know if it works for you

Do changes in your gradle like this

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true  // put this line in your gradle
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    //put below code in your gradle
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'  //put this dependencies in your gradle
    // Rest of your dependencies
}
```

& also changes in your application file.

```
public class TestApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

&

In manifest file >> in application tag >> mention below line

```
android:name=".TestApplication"
```

Hope this will work for you & if it is work then let me know.